# Why I have to press the button twice to deactivate the GameObject for the first time?

Tags: unity, unityscript

*game engine:unity3d*

*scripting language: unityscript*

code:

```
   var setmenu:GameObject; 

  var settings_menu:boolean;

   function Start()        {

   settings_menu=false; 

  }
   function settingButtonClick(){ 

  if(settings_menu==false)
  { 
  setmenu.SetActive(true);
    settings_menu=true; 

  }
         else
  { 
  setmenu.SetActive(false);      
   settings_menu=false; 
   }
 }
```

The problem is I have to click the UI button twice to SetActive to become false for the 1st time.
But after that when I again  activate and then press to deactivate it works fine with single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the `Start()` you're setting the variable `settings_menu` to false, then you're checking whether that variable is false or not. Since it is false at first, it will set the menu active on your first press of the button.

The problem you have is *not* the function, but rather the fact that you're setting a preset value instead of [checking whether the menu is active or not](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) at start. What you should be doing is this:

```
Start()
{
 settings_menu = setmenu.activeSelf; //set the state of the menu to the variable instead.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of trying in if statement you can try this

setmenu.SetActive(!settings_menu);
   settings_menu=!settings_menu;

with out if statement and i think this should work fine

Comment: Still not working

Comment: But thanks this reduces the script length